# How to Count multiple columns of a table, that could have nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with following structure:

```
============================================================================================
Id    ReferenceNo   ApprovedBy    ApprovedOn           RejectedBy     RejectedOn
============================================================================================
1      R123456      admin     2022-08-17 14:22:19.243     u1      2022-08-15 18:50:49.547
2      R128456      NULL      NULL                        u2      2022-08-12 17:20:29.873
3      R129456      u3        2022-08-19 16:50:29.123     u1      2022-08-15 18:50:49.923
4      R125456      admin     2022-08-17 11:33:49.243     NULL    NULL
5      R127456      u2        2022-08-15 10:19:29.103     u1      2022-08-15 18:34:26.713
```

I am trying to count the approved and rejected records in this table by usernames in ApprovedBy and RejectedBy columns. The following output is what I am looking for:

```
=============================================
Username    Approved    Rejected
=============================================
admin       2             0
u1          0             3
u2          1             1
u3          1             0
```

I have tried this query, but due to a null value in ApprovedBy not getting the count for RejectedBy for some users.

```
    SELECT ApprovedBy 'Username', COALESCE(COUNT(Id), 0) 'Approved', 
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblItems rej
           WHERE RejectedOn >= '06/01/2022 00:00:00.000' 
             AND RejectedOn <= '08/17/2022 23:59:59.997' 
             AND RejectedBy is not null 
             AND app.ApprovedBy=rej.RejectedBy
           GROUP BY RejectedBy
         ),0) 'Rejected' FROM tblItems app
   WHERE ApprovedOn >= '06/01/2022 00:00:00.000' 
    AND  ApprovedOn <= '08/17/2022 23:59:59.997' 
    AND ApprovedByIS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY ApprovedBy
```

Comment: Presumably you have a table with all your users in it?

Comment: Yes, there is a table with users.

Comment: Why should user3 get credit for an approved transaction? Isn't that date out of bounds?

Comment: First it was rejected then approved..

Comment: The item can be either Approved/Rejected by a user, in this particular record the user u1 first rejected it and then u3 approved it. There is no specific timeframe for the approval or rejection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unambiguous dates and avoid trying to find the "end" of the day, because that is prone to breaking if the data types change anywhere. Much safer to use `less than the next day` ([more details here](https://sqlblog.org/dates)). Anyway one way to solve the problem you're having is to use conditional aggregation:

```
DECLARE @start date = '20220601',
        @end   date = '20220818'; 

SELECT u.Username, 
  Approved = SUM(CASE WHEN i.ApprovedBy = u.Username THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  Rejected = SUM(CASE WHEN i.RejectedBy = u.Username THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM dbo.Users AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblItems AS i
ON  
(
  (
    u.Username = i.ApprovedBy 
    AND i.ApprovedOn >= @start 
    AND i.ApprovedOn < @end
  )
  OR 
  (
    u.Username = i.RejectedBy
    AND i.RejectedOn >= @start 
    AND i.RejectedOn < @end
  )
)
GROUP BY u.Username;
```

This also corrects a logic error in your current query that uses the *rejected* date to credit `u3` with an *approval* that happened outside your desired range, and includes rows from `Users` that don't have any approvals or rejections.

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da543dcbfaa9651207da12211bc9b4f6)

If you don't want to include users that are in the `Users` table and don't have any matching rows in `tblItems`, just change `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that join and conditional aggregation worked perfectly.

Comment: TBH I would probably do these as two separate queries and join them afterwards in derived tables. `OR` always scares me in a join. Race your horses I guess, good answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

If the conditional logic of timeframes doesn't really play any role, the result can be achieved by unpivoting approved and rejected columns, then pivoting approved/rejected rows to columns.

```
 with cte as (
  select id,
  cast(approvedby as varchar(30)) as approved,
  cast(rejectedby as varchar(30)) as rejected
  from 
  (values
(1, 'R123456', 'admin', '2022-08-17 14:22:19.243', 'u1', '2022-08-15 18:50:49.547'),
(2, 'R128456',  NULL,    NULL,                     'u2', '2022-08-12 17:20:29.873'),
(3, 'R129456', 'u3',    '2022-08-19 16:50:29.123', 'u1', '2022-08-15 18:50:49.923'),
(4, 'R125456', 'admin', '2022-08-17 11:33:49.243',  NULL, NULL),
(5, 'R127456', 'u2',    '2022-08-15 10:19:29.103', 'u1', '2022-08-15 18:34:26.713')
  ) as t(Id, ReferenceNo, ApprovedBy, ApprovedOn, RejectedBy, RejectedOn)
  )
select 
*
from cte
unpivot (username for y in (approved,rejected)) upv
pivot (count(id) for y in ([approved],[rejected])) pv
```